# не получается подключить расширение php_rar.dll в php

Tags: php, mamp

в php.ini вот

```
extension=php_rar.dll
```

в вызываемом файле вот

```
$filename = "fileupload.rar";
$filepath = "/";

$rar_file = rar_open($filepath.$filename);
$list = rar_list($rar_file);
foreach($list as $file) {
    $entry = rar_entry_get($rar_file, $file);
    $entry->extract("/temp"); // извлечь в текущий каталог
}
rar_close($rar_file);
```

логи php вот

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function rar_open() in D:\sites\localhost\put.php:25
```

пробывал различные версии подключать не помогло

в phpinfo расширения php_rar нету

PHP Version 7.3.7

для поднятия сервера использую mamp pro 4.1.0.23975

Comment: есть какие-либо сооброжения?

Answer (score 0):

> не получается подключить расширение php_rar.dll в php

При условии, что Вы всё установили как нужно.

1. Версия 32bit or 64bit https://pecl.php.net/package/rar
2. DLL скопировали в `MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.7/ext/php_rar.dll`

Подключить эту самую DLL в `MAMP/conf/php7.3.7/`

Answer (score 0):

**решил данную проблему следуя этому алгоритму.**

1. узнать архитектуру php.exe(32bit или 64bit) а также (TS или NTS) инфа из phpinfo();
2. скачать плагин из https://pecl.php.net/ основоваясь на инфе из первого пункта
3. проверить путь подключение конфигуратора(php.ini) инфа из phpinfo();
4. добавить extension=ваш плагин   в php.ini путь до которого узнал из третего пункта
5. добавить плагин.dll(бинарник) в extension_dir инфа из phpinfo();
6. перезагрузить сервер
7. проверить логи если нужно подк зависемые плагины подключаем  по пунктам(1 - 7)
8. **enjoy**